# Question regarding transistor codes

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp

I needed a 2N 2222A transistor. And from a electronics shop I got the transistor with following symbols,

KSP
2222A
-1426

I have already searched and know  that KSP is the name of a manufacturing company.
KSP - Components, Semiconductors, Capacitors

1. I want to know what the last digits mean?
2. I also do not know whether it's NPN or PNP.

Comment: If you grant that the part is a version of the 2N2222, why do you have any doubt about PNP or NPN?

Comment: I know that 2N2222 indicates NPN. But the transistor has 2222A written over it. Not 2N2222. That's why I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple google search of "KSP 2222A" would have returned on the first line [this datasheet](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/2n2222t.pdf), which clearly states what a KSP 2222A is.

[image]

It's basically the 2N2222A in plastic package (exactly the same specs), therefore is an NPN.

The 1426 is likely a production date-code. 2014, 26th week.

Note:
The 2N2222 (without A), instead, has smaller ratings (breakdown voltages) and performance (smaller f<sub>T</sub>) with respect to 2N2222A and its plastic version PN2222A-KSP2222A.

Comment: I had done google search and tried to read exactly this data sheet but couldn't understand.  So thanks a lot for helping me.